# What should we recycle from old pcs?

Tags: hardware, desktop

We are getting rid of about 10 old pcs but we want to make sure that we don't throw out any useful hardware. This is the list of parts we are keeping from each:

- working hard drives
- bios batteries
- ram
- working psus

Are there any other parts worth keeping? (The pcs are mostly Fujitsu Scenics & Esprimos btw).

Comment: Downvotes? I think this is a relevant question for sys admins responsible for hardware.

Comment: I'm not convinced the RAM will be worth keeping, depending on how old the machines are.  BIOS batteries probably aren't, either, as they're easily replaceable and do, you know, discharge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pile of out-of-date computer components is significantly less valuable than an out-of-date but working computer. Trying to salvage parts from old computers is only cost effective when you have comparable models still in use which you want to keep spares for - and even then, it's much simpler just to keep the whole machine. Regarding the specific things you're thinking about extracting....

- hard drives
  Along with PSUs, the most common thing to fail on PC. Both degrade gradually over their lifespan, therefore should be replaced with new units
- bios batteries
  Really? How much do you think these cost? And they wear out too
- ram
  OK, maybe, but since the connectors, speed and other properties change regularly, out-of-date memory will only work in out-of-date computers
- working PSUs
  See above

Either keep the whole computer or give the whole, working computer away (there are lots of NPOs who would be glad to take them off your hands without the problems of WEEE)

Comment: Thanks symcbean - I do agree with your final thoughts here but if we have a working computer we use it. And we have many old similar models. PSUs, bios batteries and hard drives are just the salvaged parts we have found useful so far.

Comment: @RMNVM Dispose of the units like symcbean suggested -- Donate them and write it off on the company's taxes. Use the tax write-off to partially offset the cost of any needed replacement components/hardware

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider keeping a couple of the laptops for parts if you have similar models still in service, as I have generally found older/obsolete laptop parts are expensive to replace. Otherwise, get rid of them. Components improve so quickly there's little value to reusing old, worn equipment.